# Designing a AC Snubber circuit for 2 hp using AC snubber

Tags: arduino, induction-motor, snubber

I am trying to control my 2 hp 240AC single phase motor with help of an arduino. Right now it is controlled via a contactor with 220-240 AC coil input voltage with help of NO and NC switches.

Following is what i am trying to achieve: Pardon my poor skills

[image: Circuit Diagram of what I am trying to achieve]

Following is the 10A relay i am planning to use to control the contractor:
[image: Generic 5v relay from amazon]

Following is the snubber circuit I have come to accept to the best of my abilities. 
[image: snubber circuit]

In the snubber circuit I am using 2000V 104J capacitor: Following is the image:

[image: snubber capacitor]

From what i could gather I am planning to use 20D271K as the varistor. Following one
[Varistor](https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Bourns/MOV-20D271K?qs=CQ3B1E%252BbPs1VcQHHgj%252BPAA%3D%3D)

My question is will this work? I apologise for poor circuit diagrams. I will get an electrician to install these. The motor will be switched on 2 times a day for roughly 30 mins.

Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why the snubber?

Comment: From what i understood, motor being an inductive load, when switched on or off will produce a voltage proportional to the rate of change of current which could be very high. 

Same would also be experienced at the other end when the coil of contactor discharges. no? So to protect my 10A relay and arduino?

Comment: Are you using an SSR or a relay?

Comment: XY problem. What is the motor or inductive current rating of the relay?

Comment: There is a contactor installed to control the motor: something like following:

https://www.amazon.in/25Amps-4Pole-Contactor-240V-Catno/dp/B07N5LY8JG/ref=sr_1_11?keywords=contactor&qid=1568740732&s=gateway&sr=8-11

I am using the following relay: I dont seem to able to find the inductive current rating of the 10A relay. The installed contactor has been working fine using NO and NC switches for past 2 years. 
The 10A relay is:
https://www.amazon.in/Generic-Channel-Relay-Module-Electronic/dp/B00C59NOHK/ref=sr_1_3?keywords=relay&qid=1568740645&s=gateway&sr=8-3

Thank you for your help

Comment: I understand this is not the right way of asking the question and instead i should have asked if i need a snubber or not? My apologies.

Comment: The RC shown in the diagram should be across the contactor coil, not across the relay contacts. You probably don't need the varistor. You seem to show a 240 volt relay coil. Is that correct, if so, a lower voltage would be better. If the contactor is properly rated for the motor, you should not need a snubber across the motor. The contactor and motor wiring need to be separated from the Arduino, preferably in a separate metal box.

Comment: Okay. so are you suggesting that i get a contactor which can be activated at lower voltages and is properly rated for my motor? because since right now my contactors that have been working fine, require 220-240 VAC to get activated so i will have to use 240 VAC relay (that connects to arduino and contactor) no? 
Thank you

Comment: If you have contactors with 220-240 VAC coils, they can be used. The relay selected to energize the contactor coil seems to be adequate. You can not really eliminate electromagnetic interference from switching the motor, so you need to protect tha Arduino as I described.

Comment: Okay thank you. Is there something else i can to reduce EMI apart from what you have said. Using a correctly rated SSR with a heat sink would negate this whole issue right?

Comment: Yes. A correctly rated SSR should eliminate most EMI concern. There is the possibility of inductively coupled 60 Hz from the power lines if they are too close to the control circuits. Also noise from other equipment connected to 240 V.

Comment: please report that the design worked or not? can't you use BAT16 to replace realy (SSR) ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't switch the load directly! There is already a contactor in the circuit whose One Job is to switch the load.  Have your relay switch the contactor coil.

Now you need a much smaller relay, and your snubbing problem is much smaller.

The contactor coil will also be an inductive load and may need snubbing, but nothing like the motor!

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do. the snubber i have put is between the coil of contactor and the relay which is connected to arduino. I dont have experience in this field that is why I am asking if the circuit that i have drawn above using the resistor (100 ohms), capacitor (0.1uF) and the said veristor is fine or am i making a mistake? one thing i am getting is the issue wont be as pronounced as between the contactor and motor so maybe i could use following snubber? contd..

Comment: cond.. 

[snubber from banggood - readymade] (https://www.banggood.in/3Pcs-RC-Resistance-Surge-Absorption-Circuit-Relay-Contact-Protection-Circuit-Electromagnetic-p-1287439.html?p=FQ040729393382015118&utm_campaign=25129675&utm_content=3312&cur_warehouse=CN)

Comment: Relays don't need snubber protection from each other, unless you're overloading the relay. I would be more concerned about snubbing the Arduino side of the small relay so you don't fry the Adruino's outputs.  That'll be DC so an overrunning diode would be fine.

Comment: Okay thank you for clearing that up. I have two questions
1. These relays have optical isolation. So if i separately power the relay using a separate 5V source (that is by removing the JD-VCC and VCC jumper), would that work?
2. Since these relays wont be dealing with high current, could i replace them with a solid state relay? contd... sorry for commenting like this

Comment: contd... [2A 240VAC Solid State Relay](https://www.amazon.in/REES52-Channel-Solid-State-Module/dp/B01KZ14EC8/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?crid=23R5ABPTH2EXP&keywords=solid+state+relay&qid=1568748424&s=gateway&sprefix=solid+state%2Caps%2C362&sr=8-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUFEV0NDQ0tFSlJMODgmZW5jcnlwdGVkSWQ9QTAxMDI4NTQyUUxMRzVZMkNHRzUxJmVuY3J5cHRlZEFkSWQ9QTAyOTY5NjYxN1pOVE1BN0hZRTFCJndpZGdldE5hbWU9c3BfYXRmJmFjdGlvbj1jbGlja1JlZGlyZWN0JmRvTm90TG9nQ2xpY2s9dHJ1ZQ==)

Comment: Mechanical relays have physical isolation.  Since you're dealing pretty much in bottom of the barrel cheap Chinese parts here, I would stick to mechanical relays, since it is less likely to be dangerous  if the  junkmongers have done a bad job.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t avoid the EMI of turn on/OFF using a ZVS controlled Triac.

E.g.

https://www.omega.com/en-us/control-and-monitoring-devices/relays/solid-state-relays/p/SSRL240-660

Comment: Yes that is an option. But I was hoping to make use of existing components. [crydom ssr](https://www.mouser.in/ProductDetail/Crydom/D2475T-10?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtq49AUx5G379DaLdPNi8npmEN%252BlfBLRhHXiFkVzVnngA%3D%3D) are my back up. But they cost close to $100 when i convert from INR (Indian Rupee)

Comment: This Omega SSR is only $28.  But you probably also want a snubber on the contactor contacts to extend their life.  Consult Omron for details

Answer (score 0):

Not likely to work well here in my opinion. You have relay and contactor in series. Relay will fail first.
The Snubbers ckt is handling both of the kick back., and it needs to be strong enough to cover both inductive loads.