# AC motor controller voltage spikes

Tags: relay, motor-controller

I'm trying to control an AC motor with an ESP32. Here it is the schematics on [https://falstad.com](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcAOaAmA7MgnGB-kA2MAFgwTRAQypBIGYqBTAWjDACgwsR6KQ0JSHRLIBQkIXBR0IFmmgkw2ZEPqQEuMIVxpW7GRvDx4hymmExIeQ9agcASlTRj1JZ2LQIplusLCUvjAIHAAmvPxuIq6Q7pShTABmAIYArgA2AC4cAO7RvLEeBe6QuRHmGJR8VYWleSSiApX5UXXlvPRS1e2cmbwWvISukUNQ0mxg0NjT0+QY2AjaFD6wJoLKMwiQuBhCWMPCCSkZ2QDm7fSq7UJBHADGdNrghMIkhO7aQatwAXJWGHhpsh6JduJgyIEOAA3OjYKRoQSwqSfMYQLYCAZfELpHovR7IvHCQLfNCkSDISCEejsBbIDDvez1OEY9wkZleHxlBqebxIgS8trdFHdQSWDg47oMpRSBlEuT0Kb0BZkehYbAI6hvVhiNoc-nw3mixn4ySs5myrnms0EsV5FEMlFG3WGiRRJ0cADOpsGYnYVVG-hAKXSHqYHHOesucV5NzGpQATuBfp1ffSfWMEaU+gj3Cn9enAxMpjNsHMFspIGhsLZ4OsS1sdntkAcQEc0lkypHOvmhZ3Dc1I7Uyo7msKh+FBx88W7W0l29knE880vMWNXdBGFjHCAKcUd0SBWv-IE49AQtxfXijXqjciZOZFMpgRowKqGsQ0IR9BArEgwCY4DMARLFgGwrDsQVCiNEUJDae1c34C08hzdMUIYSFkMRdC92wyDWXoGpcwDLkHTxNkbXsc5uCkbDqPyMVEzo5c01w4wTDKKI8wI4Q8zgtM8xQ3iOMiQpuhBeE+y6KDeXEgRhy6UYGWXMpdyiMcSg4AB7cAkFlPxphkakvBrbZ6W8Yy5RsegtKTb1Xm2asYEICzviwAI-wEWzrKAA). I've simplified the AC motor coils with 2H coils, maybe I should place a resistor to make it more realistic but I'm not sure if that would change something for this question.

[image]

I've found several problems which I don't know how to solve:

- The Main Circuit Breaker goes off every once and then (I've even burned some low isolation relays). I'm almost sure this is because of voltage spikes when switching on and off the relays which powers the motor. Playing with falstad it seems that depending on the current phase, the voltage could raise up to some thousands of kV. I've been searching on how to place a snubber, found question here [Designing a AC Snubber circuit for 2 hp using AC snubber](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458956/designing-a-ac-snubber-circuit-for-2-hp-using-ac-snubber) but I'm not sure on how to place it in this circuit. I'm asking if someone could help me to place it, any example circuit or falstad schematic would be very helpful.
- I'm not sure if this circuit is introducing some harmonics/interferences or reactive energy, in this case, how could it be corrected?
- The controller is placed inside a garage with some old neon lights. When switching off some of the neon lights, suddenly the motor starts spinning. I'm not sure on what could be done in order to filter the interferences. Also not sure on how to detect them and who is being affected, if it is the relays or the MCU.

**EDIT**

Schematics:

[image]

Layout, this is approximate, as for the prototype I'm wiring with manual soldering with cables:

[image]

Comment: Welcome! _"When switching off some of the neon lights, suddenly the motor starts spinning."_ EMI issue. Show schematic and layout. Snubber across the relay contacts comes to mind too.

Comment: Thanks @winny, I've shared the schematic here: https://oshwlab.com/miqmago/motors_brico, layout done by hand with cables and grid pcb. The EMI filter is a proposal (never tried), I've started reading about it from your comment, but not really sure about C and L values, help very welcome... Also for the snubber, as I'm not sure on how to design it and the values for R, C and which varistor could be used. The circuit is little bit more complex: UP_DOWN inverts the motor direction by switching the connection between the coils. Also I've been thinking to use 12V for relays and get better relays

Comment: another option I've been thinking is to use some commercial option like [this one](https://es.aliexpress.com/item/4000165222365.html) for EMI filter

Comment: Please embed your layout in the question. How many layers are you using?

Comment: @winny added layout and schematics, for the prototype I'm manual soldering everything with cables, so I could not talk about layers as there are no layers at all. In the schematics I've designed what I think it could work: the EMI filter and a new power source for 12V relays, it would mean to use different relays too... So thanks to your help, now the main questions are: Would this EMI filter work in terms of not breaking anything? How to place a snubber circuit  (values for R, C and varistor and how to connect them)? Makes sense to use 12V relays, would it change anything?

Comment: That’s unfortunately a bad two layer design. You need to dedicate the bottom layer to ground and only use very short traces on it where necessary. If you are not going to mass produce these, there is no reason not to make this a four layer design with dedicated ground and Vcc layers. Unless the ESP is a module with its own decoupling, then you are completely lacking decoupling capacitors. Next off, snubbers across the relays.

Comment: @winny what I've been thinking for a production design is to put all AC traces with phisical separation, I mean with a hole in the board. Right now the layout is made with cables, so no traces at all. The ESP devkit v1 it already comes with some decoupling capacitors from what I've seen in the schematics, but I will also place some more outside the board.

Comment: Regarding the EMI filter, could you help me to tell if it is well designed, meaning schematics and values? Also for the snubbers, is there any place where I could read on how to design it? Meaning where to connect and which values to select for capacitor, resistance and varistor?

Comment: Good. Measurement is best, but fast brute force testing of an EMI problem is to add decoupling capacitors and observe if that makes any difference. Have you simulated any RC filter across the relays? Your end goal is to limit dI/dt without getting too high peak power in the resistor or unreasonably large capacitor.

Comment: Ok, will place capacitors and see. Honestly have no idea on how to design this kind of RC filter, I'm not really experienced in AC circuits...

Comment: @winny the only place I've seen there is something I could try is https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/458956/designing-a-ac-snubber-circuit-for-2-hp-using-ac-snubber but not sure if it is correct and if the values would work in this case...

Comment: Yes, like that. Please simulate it. It’s easy to get too high peak power in the resistor. Assume you hit the peak of the AC cycle or zero crossing, depending on what’s the worst case given your load.